# Ruby On Rails Rspec require conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The following is my problem I have Rspec installed started a project in it every-time I want to test something have to `require_relative` it now this wasn't a problem until I wanted to finally test my controllers and cant seem to get the functions `get` , `post` constantly getting `undefined function` error.

If I put my controller like this

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationController, :type => :controller do

end
```

I am receiving `uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)` if i require relative the application controller like this `require_relative '../../app/controllers/application_controller'` I get `uninitialized constant ActionController (NameError)` .

Can't seem to catch where the problem might be here is my `Gemfile` also

```
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
gem "rspec", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

I have been browsing the internet for 2 hours now viewd at least 10 other stackoverflow questions tried everything but nothing seems to be working ...

Everywhere I check they say that I should only need to add `require 'spec_helper'` and it should work but its not.

I can copy my rails_helper file also if needed but its the standard what came with it when I ran `rails generate rspec:install` .

Your help is much appreciated I really need to fix this because I am running out of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of rspec-rails 3 the auto generated spec_helper.rb is split into two parts: spec_helper.rb and rails_helper.rb

The idea is that you can have specs that don't need rails loaded (and so are  fast to load) as well as specs that do need rails loaded

For ones that do need rails loaded, like your controller spec you need to do

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

At the top, instead of requiring spec_helper.

Comment: Hmmm oke for some reason the test runs but I get at least 200+ lines of error and after it runs any idea? Tell me if you would like for me to paste in at least the main parts of the errors but there are a lot of them.

Comment: The default .rspec (either in project folder or in your home folder) file is created with the --warnings option turned on. Removing that should get rid of those.

Comment: 100 thanks now I see my main problem somehow is with PostgreSQL.